# How to unit test views with helper functions in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-4, helper

I have these test cases visiting urls and checking for right behavior but I cant make it work because it errors on my helper functions within the view.

It works on the browser but not in tests.

```
    /** @test */
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

    }

    /** @test **/   
    public function openAdminDashboardUnauthorized()
    {    
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', 'admin/organizations');
        $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isOk());

    }

    /** @test **/
    public function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();            
    }
```

heres the error

[image]

**EDIT**
My helper classes are loaded in the global.php in the classLoader
by the way, this is on laravel 4.2

**UPDATE**

People say that you have to mock helper functions in order to unit test them. But in my case the helper functions are in the views and I tested dumping a static message from the setup function and indeed it was not loaded during the test run time.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I found working.

Loaded my helper class in the composer.json autoload sub tree

and run a quick "composer dump-autoload"

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/helper/Helper.php"
        ]
    }
```

Now I know the difference between loading classes in global.php and autoloaded through composer. If anyone could explain more on the sequence in which laravel boots the application, I'll accept.

Comment: You will have much better idea on the Laravel's Request Cycle see https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

use Mockery, laravel4.2 has it by default. see https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/testing
You should have something like this at the top.

```
use Mockery as m;

class ClassToTest
{
    public function test_some_method()
    {
        // Mock view helper
        $viewHelperMock = m::mock(ViewHelper::class);

        // Set expectations
        $viewHelperMock->shouldReceive('show');
        ...

        // This must be done only after setting the expectations
        $this->app->instance(ViewHelper::class, $viewHelperMock);

        ...
        // Your assertions goes here
        }
}
```

We are binding our own `viewHelperMock` instance to Laravel's DI container. So whenever the request for ViewHelper class is made, it resolves to our mock instance. So, now you can set the expectations for all of the methods that are called in your view helper.

If you show us your view (html) code then it will be more easier to guide you. Don't get upset, it is tricky and confusing at the beginning. So, give it try multiple time also look at how [Laravel's IOC container](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc) works.

Let us know if you have any problem following it.